# Incorrect Number of bindings supplied error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
  def login():
    loggedIn = False
    userInput = input("please enter your username: ")
    pwdInput = input("please enter your password: ")
    searchUser = hashlib.md5(userInput.encode()).hexdigest()
    searchPwd = hashlib.md5(pwdInput.encode()).hexdigest()
    query = """SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE Username =?;"""
    cursor.execute(query, searchUser)
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    if record:
       print("found")
```

Sorry the indenting is bad but isn't in the actual thing

I have this code set up to take in inputs and then hash them, I want to search the table "Users" to find the "Username". But it keeps saying "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1 and there are 32 supplied.

I tried combining the query and variables into 1 line and it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a tuple (or other sequence) of query parameters, even if there's only one:

```
cursor.execute(query, (searchUser,))
```

By passing `searchUser` on its own, without wrapping it, you're telling the cursor to treat the individual characters of `searchUser` as separate query parameters.